# CorruptedFrameException data frame using reserved opcode 7

Tags: java, websocket, netty

I am trying to establish a web socket communication behind my corporate proxy. I can see that the proxy connection between my proxy server and remote host established and get back handshake response. After that when I try to send a message I get the exception.

Here is my channel init

```
Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
        b.group(group).channel(NioSocketChannel.class).handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
            @Override
            protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
                ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();

                if (sslCtx != null) {
                    p.addFirst("ssl", sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc(), host, port));
                }
                if(proxyHandler != null){
                    p.addFirst("proxyHandler", proxyHandler);

                }
                p.addLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.DEBUG));
                p.addLast("clientCodec", new HttpClientCodec());

                p.addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder());
                p.addLast("aggregator", new HttpObjectAggregator(65536));
                p.addLast("encoder", new HttpResponseEncoder());
                p.addLast(handler);


            }
        });
```

And exception is

> ```
> io.netty.handler.codec.CorruptedFrameException: data frame using reserved opcode 7
>   at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocket08FrameDecoder.protocolViolation(WebSocket08FrameDecoder.java:412)
>   at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocket08FrameDecoder.decode(WebSocket08FrameDecoder.java:229)
>   at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411)
>   at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:351)
>   at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373)
>   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
>   at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926)
>   at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:129)
>   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:651)
>   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:574)
>   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:488)
>   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:450)
>   at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:873)
>   at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> WebSocket Client
> disconnected!
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I have run into the same issue and found out that this issue appears as a result of the WebSocket upgrade operation as reported here: [WebSocket upgrade wrecks HttpProxyHandler](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/5201). Leaving a note in case anyone has the same problem.

The important part quoted:

> Short story: WebSocketClientHandshaker reorganizes the Pipeline after
>   receiving the upgrade from the server. If there is an HttpProxyHandler
>   in the Pipeline, it has installed its own HttpClientCodec which gets
>   wrecked by WebSocketClientHandshaker.
>
> ```
> HttpClientCodec#0        <-- #finishHandshake hit this one.
> ws-decoder               <-- We don't want this here.
> ws-encoder               <-- We don't want this here.
> Http11ProxyHandler#0
> SslHandler#0
> HttpClientCodec#1
>                          <-- ws-xxcoder should appear here.
> DownendChannelHandler#0  <-- My own stuff.
> ```

It seems there is no fix yet so one may need to hack into the WebSocketClientHandshaker or the post references kind of a workaround.